# PHP import using txt file

Tags: php, database, import

I am using following code for importing data into database using txt file

```
while (!feof($handle)) // Loop til end of file.
{



    $buffer = fgets($handle, 4096); // Read a line.

    $data_array =explode("|",$buffer);//Separate string by the means of |

    $escaped_array = array_map('mysql_escape_string',$data_array);

    $escaped_array = '("'.implode('","',$escaped_array).'") ';


    if($i !=1) {
       echo $sql = 'INSERT INTO '.$tablename.' VALUES'.$escaped_array; 
        mysql_query($sql) ; //or die(mysql_error().$tablename);// use mysql insert query here
        //exit;
    }

    $i++;
} //end while
```

it inserting values like 
INSERT INTO PROVIDER_DEMOGRAPHIC VALUES("10000104","Sand","David","C","MD","Family Practice","","N","N","N","P","125\r\r\n") INSERT INTO PROVIDER_DEMOGRAPHIC VALUES("10000105","Stucky","Mitchell","B","MD","Family Practice","","N","N","N","P","101\r\r\n")

I donot want extra character in last fiels like \r\n\r Please tell me how i can trim it.

Comment: Use `fgetcsv` and set delimiter to `|` instead of the default `,`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reading the newline characters from the file, and may need to trim it

Use:

```
$buffer = fgets($handle, 4096); // Read a line.
$buffer = rtrim($buffer);
$escaped_array = array_map('mysql_escape_string',$data_array);
```

**Warning:** `mysql_` function is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used.